# How to capture Raspberry Pi HQ camera data in YUV format using PiCamera2?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, picamera

I'm trying to use an ArduCam version of the Raspberry Pi HQ camera with IR-cut to take successive RGB and near-infrared images for vegetation analysis. I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3B with a fresh installation of Raspbian Bullseye completely updated. I'm using the new picamera2 python library, but the documentation doesn't provide clear examples of taking YUV images. I have tried reverting to legacy camera option and using picamera library, but this is creating errors, and I figured picamera2 should be able to take YUV images since the format appears to exist.

Here is the code I am running:

```
### I use this script to take RGB and near-IR images in rapid succession by modulating the
### IR filter in the camera using GPIO control.

### Import libraries
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from picamera2 import Picamera2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Configure camera
picam2 = Picamera2()

### Initial GPIO setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) # use GPIO numbering
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT) # set GPIO23 as an output

### Take IR image in YUV format
capture_config = picam2.create_still_configuration(main = {"size": (4056, 3040), "format": "YUV420"})
#capture_config = picam2.create_still_configuration()
picam2.configure(capture_config)
picam2.start()
GPIO.output(23, 0)
time.sleep(2)
arr_ir = picam2.capture_array("main")
picam2.stop()

### Take RGB image
capture_config = picam2.create_still_configuration()
picam2.configure(capture_config)
picam2.start()
GPIO.output(23, 1)
time.sleep(2)
arr_rgb = picam2.capture_array("main")
picam2.stop()

### Clear GPIO
GPIO.cleanup()

### Plot the images
f, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax[0].imshow(arr_rgb)
ax[0].set_title('RGB')
ax[1].imshow(arr_ir)
ax[1].set_title('No IR')
plt.show()
```

And, the console output:

```
Python 3.9.2 (/usr/bin/python3)
>>> %Run picam3.py
[0:48:47.805476153] [2206]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:293 libcamera v0.0.0+3866-0c55e522
[0:48:47.863042202] [2209]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:1374 Registered camera /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx477@1a to Unicam device /dev/media3 and ISP device /dev/media0
[0:48:47.873313630] [2206]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1035 configuring streams: (0) 4056x3040-YUV420
[0:48:47.874221436] [2209]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:761 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx477@1a - Selected sensor format: 4056x3040-SBGGR12_1X12 - Selected unicam format: 4056x3040-pBCC
[0:48:52.068604089] [2212]  INFO Camera camera.cpp:1035 configuring streams: (0) 4056x3040-BGR888
[0:48:52.081509246] [2209]  INFO RPI raspberrypi.cpp:761 Sensor: /base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/imx477@1a - Selected sensor format: 4056x3040-SBGGR12_1X12 - Selected unicam format: 4056x3040-pBCC
>>> print(arr_ir.shape)
(4560, 4096)
>>>
```

Using the code above, instead of producing the YUV array I would expect and hope for, I am left with an odd 2-dimensional array that has some reproduced image artifacts as seen in the image below. I would love to use picamera2 to capture a YUV array that is 4056x3040x3 as is easily possible in picamera using "camera.capture('image.data', 'yuv')". I would appreciate any help or guidance here.

[image: Plot of RGB and YUV images taken using script above.]

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for, but... the the image you have on the right looks weird for two reasons. Firstly, you have use `matplotlib` and its default `viridis` colourmap instead of `grey` colourmap. Secondly, it is not really an *"artefact"*, it is a YUV image where the upper, large image is the Y channel, and the two images below are the downsampled U and V channels, i.e. they have half the width and half the height of the full-size YUV. This is effectively *"chroma-subsampling"*.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification Mark! I didn't realize that is how the YUV matrix is built. In this case, I should have what I need.